# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) when scaping SEC EDGAR

Tags: python, edgar, sec

My codes are as follows:

```
import requests
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

year_url = r"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/daily-index/2020/index.json"
year_content = requests.get(year_url)
decoded_year_url = year_content.json()
```

I could run the exactly same codes last year, but when I ran it yesterday, the warning popped up:
"JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
Why? How should I solve the problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `print(year_content.text)`, output : `We do not offer technical support for developing or debugging scripted downloading processes` get error

Comment: The website doesn't want to serve robots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the SEC has added rate-limiting to their website, according to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/joeyism/py-edgar/issues/24) from May 2021. The reason why you're receiving the error message is that the response contains HTML, rather than JSON, which causes `requests` to raise an error upon calling `.json()`.

To resolve this, you need to add the `User-agent` header to your request. I can access the JSON with the following:

```py
import requests
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

year_url = r"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/daily-index/2020/index.json"
year_content = requests.get(year_url, headers={'User-agent': '[specify user agent here]'})
decoded_year_url = year_content.json()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try importing json module and use the method json.loads()

```
import requests
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

year_url = r"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/daily-index/2020/index.json"
year_content = requests.get(year_url)
decoded_year_url = json.loads(year_content)
```

Comment: This isn't a JSON-related issue. The request is returning HTML as part of a 403 Forbidden response.